# Replace the text in sed

Tags: sed

I have

```
<funcprototype>
                <funcdef>void <function>foo</function></funcdef>
                <paramdef>int <parameter>target</parameter></paramdef>
                <paramdef>char <parameter>name</parameter></paramdef>
</funcprototype>
<funcprototype>
                <funcdef>void <function>foo2</function></funcdef>
                <paramdef>int <parameter>target2</parameter></paramdef>
                <paramdef>char <parameter>name2</parameter></paramdef>
</funcprototype>
```

I need to get : `void foo( int tagret char name)
            void foo2( int tagre2 char name2)`
Using sed I can do

```
void foo(
int target
char name
)
void foo2(
int target2
char name2
)
```

I do it using this command

```
awk "/\<funcprototype\>/,/\<\/funcprototype\>/ { print }" foo.xml | sed 's/^[ ^t]*//;s/[ ^]*$//'|sed -e '/^$/d'|sed 's/ //g'| sed 's/<funcprototype>//;s/<funcdef>//;s/<function>/ /;s/<\/function><\/funcdef>/(/;s/<paramdef>//;s/<parameter>/ /;s/<\/parameter><\/paramdef>//;s/<\/funcprototype>/)/;'
```

How can I do what i want?

Comment: Do you want `tagret` or `target` ?

Comment: Post your `sed` command using which you obtained the alternate form.  We'll help you fix it.

Comment: awk "/\<funcprototype\>/,/\<\/funcprototype\>/ { print }" "${file}" | sed  's/^[ ^t]*//;s/[ ^]*$//'|sed -e '/^$/d'|sed  's/ //g'| sed 's/<funcprototype>//;s/<funcdef>//;s/<function>/ /;s/<\/function><\/funcdef>/\(/;s/<paramdef>//;s/<parameter>/ /;s/<\/parameter><\/paramdef>//;s/<\/funcprototype>/\)/;'

Comment: No, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23058037/edit). Your attempt is part of the question.

Comment: You got an useful answer, but try to use a proper XML parser for parsing XML. XML is not "text" of the kind that sed and regular expressions in general are meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing file formats like XML in sed is always a hack, so the "correct" solution highly depends on what inputs you want to except. The following sed script at least works fine on the example data you provided:

```
:loop
/<\/funcprototype>/ ! { N; b loop; }
s/\n/ /g;

s/<\/\?\(funcdef\|parameter\|function\|funcprototype\)>//g;
s/<paramdef>/(/g;
s/<\/paramdef>/)/g;
s/) *(/, /g;

s/  */ /g;
s/^ //;
s/ $//;
s/ (/(/;
```

The interesting bit is the `:loop` part in the first two lines: The `:loop` line defines a label and the 2nd line appends the next line from the input to the buffer and jumps back to the label until the buffer contains the closing `</funcprototype>` tag. So after this two commands a whole multi-line `<funcprototype> .. </funcprototype>` block is in the buffer (with `\n` characters separating the lines). The newline characters are then replaced with blanks using the command `s/\n/ /g` in the 3rd line.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot understand why you solution does not work with functions which have 2 or more arguments.

Comment: @user3288344 Maybe you could add examples for that to the question?

Comment: @user3288344 I've now made the necessary changes to my answer to make it work with two or more parameters.